# How to select the child element using Xpath in WebdriverIO

Tags: xpath, webdriver-io

there are multiple elements if I provide the child class directly. So need to extract the child on the basis of parent. Need child text "A value is required for this field." on the basis of parent where id=cardholderName

```
<div class="col-12 has-error" id="cardholderNameFieldInput">
            <input id="cardholderName" name="cardholderName" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="true" style="height: 34px; padding: 0px 12px; font-size: 14px; border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); border-radius: 2px;">
            <div class="fieldError">A value is required for this field.</div>
          </div>
```

This gives me the parent but how to get the child text with this?

`//input[@id="cardholderName"]`

Comment: `input`is the previous-sibling of the needed one. Try `//div[@id="cardholderNameFieldInput]/input[@id="cardholderName"]/following-sibling::div`

Comment: Take into account that the xpath above will get any <div> child element that is after the <input>, being that the one you want or not.